# $ionicLoading not showing during list fetch from Firebase in Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, angularfire

I have a Firebase data store that I access to load a list. I would like to show a $ionicLoading indicator till the list loads completely and is actually displayed on the page.

For some reason, it seems that the $ionicLoading does come up but its for such a short time that it doesn't even show. Yet on the page, the list still takes 1-3 seconds to load and be displayed. Am I doing this wrong?

My controllers.js section is as follows:

```
.controller('ListCtrl', function($scope, ListService, LoaderService) {
  var message="Loading list...";
  LoaderService.showLoader(message);

  ListService.listAll().then(function(data){
    $scope.list = data;
    LoaderService.hideLoader();
  });
})
```

My services.js section that returns the list promise is as follows:

```
.factory('ListService', function($q, $firebaseArray) {

    var refList = 
    new Firebase('https://my-list-db.firebaseIO.com/coupons');

    return {
        listAll: function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var items = $firebaseArray(refList);
            deferred.resolve(items);
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
})

.factory('LoaderService', function($ionicLoading){
    //var LoadingObj= new $ionicLoading;

    return {
        showLoader: function(loadingMessage){
            //loadingMessage="Loading List...";
            $ionicLoading.show({
                template: loadingMessage
            });
        },

        hideLoader: function(){
            $ionicLoading.hide();
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to resolve a `$firebaseArray()` in a promise, as it returns a promise when it is loaded with `$loaded()`.

Try this instead:

```
.constant('FirebaseUrl', 'https://my-list-db.firebaseIO.com/')
.service('rootRef', ['FirebaseUrl', Firebase])
.factory('ListService', function(rootRef, $firebaseArray) {
   var refList = rootRef.child('coupons');
   return $firebaseArray(refList);
})
.controller('ListCtrl', function($scope, ListService, LoaderService) {
   var message = "Loading list...";
   LoaderService.showLoader(message);

   $scope.list = ListService;

   $scope.list.$loaded.then(function(data){
      LoaderService.hideLoader();
   });
})
```

However, you should know that `$loaded()` is generally not needed. Because when the data loads, AngularFire triggers the `$digest` loop and the data will appear on the screen. So you can assign the `ListService` to scope, and then resolve `$loaded()` to know when to dismiss the `LoaderService`.

**[Check out the AngularFire API for more information.](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-loaded)**

Comment: Hmm...lol good to know that haha! I'll give it a try! Thanks David!

Comment: Yep! Look at my updated answer for more details on `$loaded()`.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a bunch. I'm still new to all of this so I'm writing crappy code still. Lol.

Comment: We all start somewhere :)

Comment: Did this help at all?

Comment: Sorry David, I was busy with the holidays. I tried it your way, but I was either not seeing the message, or the $loaded was giving me errors. I finally just decided to go with a declarative method. I placed a div section on my list page that conditionally displayed a "loading..." message, which disappeared once the list had more than zero elements in it.

Comment: `.controller('ListCtrl', 
  function($scope, ListService, current_Auth) {
  $scope.callbackMessage = ListService.dataCallbackMessage.toString();
  $scope.list = ListService.listAll();
})' and my html became: '<ion-content>
   <div class="bar bar-header bar-dark" ng-show="!list.length">
   <p>{{callbackMessage}}</p>
   </div>

    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="item in list">
        {{item.Title}} 
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>`

Comment: And my ListService returned a callBackMessage object that had the message: "Loading list. Please wait..."

Answer (score 0):

You can use $loaded with an instance of a factory or service to show loading message and hide it when the data are loaded.

```
.factory("Trendingpackages", function($firebaseArray) {
   var TrendingpackagesRef = new Firebase("https://brilliant-torch-4678.firebaseio.com/items");
   return $firebaseArray(TrendingpackagesRef);
 })
```

Then you can use it within a controller:

```
.controller('TrendingpackagesCtrl', function($scope, Trendingpackages, $ionicLoading) {


  var trendingpackages = [];


  $ionicLoading.show({
    template: 'Loading...'
  });


  $scope.trendingpackages = Trendingpackages;

  Trendingpackages.$loaded().then(function(){
    $ionicLoading.hide();
  })

})
```